# How to minimize column of a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have property site, I have a table in my database property, in which property details are supposed to be saved. I have a huge list of property and each property has too many features. there are almost 50 feature options that user can check so what should I do now, should I made 50 column, each column for each feature or is there any other way? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for a better database design  if the options feauture are not fixed   you should avoid a fixed  schema and prefer   master detail relationship

```
property
--------
id_property
name_property 


feature 
-------
id_feature
name_feature

property_feature_relationship
-----------------------------
id
id_property
id_feature
```

Comment: so i add 40 column in feature table ??

Comment: So you add  the rows you need  (not column )  but rows .. and just for the feature you need .. then you have two columns  (id_feature, name_feature) and  the values are store in different rows .. this for matching the feature you want assign to each property .. so if you have 40 values you have 40 rows

Comment: and i will make a property_id which will be the foreign key with the property table column id ??

Comment: Is a 'feature' true/false, such as 'garbage disposal'?  Or numeric, such as 'bedrooms'?  Or string, such as 'school district'?

Comment: feature is a id, name table  ... (1, feature1) (2, feature2 ) (3,featur3)   is the collectio of you feautures list  ... (seems you haven't never seen a relational db table)